# mpdf yii2 throwing error Undefined offset: 0 for tableLevel

Tags: yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

I am using kartik-v/yii2-mpdf v1.0.5 and simply printing html content into the pdf.

but recently I started facing issue without any change in code

my code:

```
$pdf = new Pdf([
    // set to use core fonts only
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
    // A4 paper format
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
    // portrait orientation
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
    // stream to browser inline
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
    // your html content input
    'content' => $content,
    // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
    // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting 
    'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
    // any css to be embedded if required
    'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
    // set mPDF properties on the fly
    'options' => ['title' => $pdfTemplate->name],
    // call mPDF methods on the fly
    'methods' => [
        'SetHeader' => [$pdfTemplate->name],
        'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}'],
    ]
]);

return $pdf->render();
```

[image]

Comment: you should add the code that is resulting in the above error, no one can guess what could be the reason without seeing the code block.

Comment: code added so its simple code nothing much i did here

Comment: var_dump($this->mpdf->table); exit;